# COPY with FORCE NULL to all fields

Tags: postgresql

I have several CSVs with varying field names that I am copying into a Postgres database from an s3 data source. There are quite a few of them that contain empty strings, `""` which I would like to convert to NULLs at import. When I attempt to copy I get an error along the lines of this (same issue for other data types, integer, etc.):

```
psycopg2.errors.InvalidDatetimeFormat: invalid input syntax for type date: ""
```

I have tried using `FORCE_NULL (field 1, field2, field3)` - and this works for me, except I would like to do `FORCE_NULL (*)` and apply to all of the columns as I have A LOT of fields I am bringing in that I'd like this applied to.

Is this available?

This is an example of my csv:
`"ABC","tgif","123","","XyZ"`

Comment: Show the actual code you are using as this seems to be passing through `psycopg2`.

Comment: Also provide example of the data in the CSV, in particular the parts with empty strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `psycopg2` [Copy](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from) functions. In this case [copy_expert](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert):

```
cat empty_str.csv 
1, ,3,07/22/2
2,test,4,
3,dog,,07/23/2022

create table empty_str_test(id integer, str_fld varchar, int_fld integer, date_fld date);

import psycopg2

con = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres host=localhost port=5432") 
cur = con.cursor() 

with open("empty_str.csv") as csv_file:
    cur.copy_expert("COPY empty_str_test FROM STDIN WITH csv", csv_file)
con.commit()

select * from empty_str_test ;

 id | str_fld | int_fld |  date_fld  
----+---------+---------+------------
  1 |         |       3 | 2022-07-22
  2 | test    |       4 | 
  3 | dog     |         | 2022-07-23
```

From here [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-copy.html):

> NULL

> Specifies the string that represents a null value. The default is \N (backslash-N) in text format, and an unquoted empty string in CSV format. You might prefer an empty string even in text format for cases where you don't want to distinguish nulls from empty strings. This option is not allowed when using binary format.

`copy_expert` allows you specify the CSV format. If you use `copy_from` it will use the text format.

Comment: how would that translate to `psycopg3` ?

Comment: `psycopg3` does not have copy_expert

Comment: See my answer here [Copy psycopg2/3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73623152/psycopg2-copy-from-is-inserting-data-with-double-quotes-when-whitespace-is-pre/73623435#73623435).