# Psycopg2 copy_from() is inserting data with double quotes when whitespace is present in csv file

Tags: python, postgresql, file, psycopg2

I am trying to import the following table to my Postgres server using cursor.copy_from() in psycopg2 because the file is too large.

| id | mail | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john123@gmail.com | John Stokes |
| 2 | emily123@gmail.com | Emily Ray |

Here is my code:

```
import psycopg2
import os

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    dbname = name,
    user = username,
    password = pwd,
    host = hst,
    port = 5432
)

cur = conn.cursor()

path = os.getcwd() + '\users.csv'

file = open(path, 'r')

cur.copy_from(file, table_name, sep=',')
conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

This inserts the data to the table but there is double quotes in the third column like below.

| id | mail | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john123@gmail.com | "John Stokes" |
| 2 | emily123@gmail.com | "Emily Ray" |

Later I found out that the problem lies in the open() itself. Because if I print the first line by doing `file.readline()`, I get:

> 1,john123@gmail.com,"John Stokes"

I don't want these double quotes in my table. I tried using cursor.execute() with `COPY FROM` query but it says that I am not a superuser even if I am.

Comment: Did you consider to just delete that quotes programatically before inserting the row?

Comment: Unfortunately your code won't work since it's missing commas in the `connect` call.

Comment: @kosciej1 The double quotes are not present in the original csv file. Also I don't want to insert the rows one by one since there are 100k+ rows

Comment: @noob_coder The double quotes are absolutely certainly there in the original CSV file if `readline()` sees them. If you're opening the file in e.g. Excel, then sure, you won't see the quotes.

Comment: @AKX I have made this code as a demo of what I am actually doing in my code. I made the correction in this post but this won't solve my actual problem

Comment: The complaint about superuser is that `COPY` runs as the server user and that user needs permissions on the file you are uising.

Comment: @AKX Yes. It's there in the readline function. But how do I remove it?

Comment: @noob_coder If you say "This is my code" if we can tell that it won't even _parse_ due to a syntax error (which is still there, by the way; see the `host = ` line), then it casts a doubt on everything _else_ in your question too. How can we trust anything to say if you aren't showing us the actual code you've tried?  **Your actual problem is only solved by making sure there aren't extra quotes in your CSV file. `COPY FROM` doesn't handle quotes.**

Comment: @Adrian Klaver Since the file is present locally, how do I give permissions to the user?

Comment: @AKX The code is present in my organizations laptop and I can't login to stackoverflow from there. So I just typed the code here by replacing the actual server name and password

Comment: You don't, I am working on answer that will show you the solution.

Comment: @AKX, you don't have to eliminate the quotes in the file as `copy_expert` using `WITH CSV` handles them just fine.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I stand corrected :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [copy_expert](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert). Then you are not working as the server user but as the client user. Also you can use `WITH CSV` which will take care of the quoting. `copy_from` and `copy_to` work using the text format as described here [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html).

```
cat test.csv                                                                                                                                                            
1,john123@gmail.com,"John Stokes"
2,emily123@gmail.com,"Emily Ray"

create table test_csv (id integer, mail varchar, name varchar);

import psycopg2

con = psycopg2.connect(dbname="test", host='localhost', user='postgres', port=5432)
cur = con.cursor()


with open('test.csv') as f:
    cur.copy_expert('COPY test_csv FROM stdin WITH CSV', f)

con.commit()

select * from test_csv ;
 id |        mail        |    name     
----+--------------------+-------------
  1 | john123@gmail.com  | John Stokes
  2 | emily123@gmail.com | Emily Ray
```

FYI, in `psycopg3(psycopg)` this behavior has changed substantially. See here [psycopg3 COPY](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/copy.html) for how to handle in that case.

**UPDATE**

Using `psycopg3` the answer for Python 3.8+ where the walrus operator is available would be:

```
import psycopg

with open('test.csv') as f:
    with cur.copy("COPY test_csv FROM STDIN WITH CSV") as copy:
        while data := f.read(1000):
            copy.write(data)
con.commit()
```

Or using Python 3.7-, something like:

```
# Function copied from here https://www.iditect.com/guide/python/python_howto_read_big_file_in_chunks.html
def read_in_chunks(file, chunk_size=1024*10):  # Default chunk size: 10k.
    while True:
        chunk = file.read(chunk_size)
        if chunk:
            yield chunk
        else: # The chunk was empty, which means we're at the end of the file
            return

with open('test.csv') as f:
    with cur.copy("COPY test_csv FROM STDIN WITH CSV") as copy:
        for chunk in read_in_chunks(f):
            copy.write(chunk)

con.commit()
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm! I used to get the HINT to use STDIN instead of directly copying from a csv file but didn't think about doing it.

Comment: A heads up this process is different in `psycopg3`. I updated answer with link to the new procedure.

Comment: if you have a composite key that where one of the pk columns is string - it should be able to accept an empty string. In my case when i use psycog3.copy (from an io buffer), its reading those empty columns as null, not string.

Comment: @mike01010. Not entirely sure what you are trying to say. At a guess though I'm saying that from here [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) you are seeing: *Specifies the string that represents a null value. The default is \N (backslash-N) in text format, and an unquoted empty string in CSV format.*