# FeatureNotSupported: COPY from a file is not supported

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

I am looking to find a faster solution than pandas to_sql to ingest a pandas df into postgres database.

```
import time
import psycopg2

df = pd.read_csv('upload_test_data.csv') 
conn = psycopg2.connect(user=username,password=password,
                        host=host,port=port,database=db)
cursor = conn.cursor()

#perform COPY test and print result
sql = '''
    COPY copy_test
    FROM 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\copy_test.csv'
    DELIMITER ',' CSV;
    '''

table_create_sql = '''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS copy_test (id                bigint,
                                      quantity          int,
                                      cost              double precision,
                                      total_revenue     double precision)
                    '''

cursor.execute(table_create_sql)
cursor.execute('TRUNCATE TABLE copy_test') 

start_time = time.time()
df.to_csv('upload_test_data_from_copy.csv', index=False, header=False) 

cursor.execute(sql)
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
print("COPY duration: {} seconds".format(time.time() - start_time))
```

The code above returns an error:

```
FeatureNotSupported: COPY from a file is not supported
```

As the goal is to automate the process, I prefer that the solution is fully in Python to switching between different software.

```
Version: PostgreSQL 13.7 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

Comment: 1) Read the docs [Psycopg2 copy](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from) 2) Look at my answer here [Psycopg2 copy_from](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from) for the solution. 3) Where is `fpl_df` coming from?

Comment: I have adjusted the query. Regarding the copy_from, the code: cursor.copy_from(df, 'copy_test', sep=",") returns an error "TypeError: argument 1 must have a .read() method"

Comment: You can't use the DataFrame(`df`) because per the message it is not a file like object and so does not have the `read()` method. You would need to use the `'upload_test_data_from_copy.csv'` file. Also why not read directly from `'upload_test_data.csv'`?

Comment: Realized I did not use correct URL for link to my answer in my first comment. It should be [Psycopg2 copy_from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73623152/psycopg2-copy-from-is-inserting-data-with-double-quotes-when-whitespace-is-pre/73623435#73623435). Take a look at it and see how you can avoid using Pandas at all.

Comment: are you sure that you provided the link to your answer? both links seem to be the docs of psycopg2.

Comment: Look at my most recent comment for corrected link.