# Using a buffer to write a psycopg3 copy result through pandas

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2, psycopg3

Using `psycopg2`, I could write large results as CSV using `copy_expert` and a `BytesIO` buffer like this with `pandas`:

```py
copy_sql = "COPY (SELECT * FROM big_table) TO STDOUT CSV"

buffer = BytesIO()
cursor.copy_expert(copy_sql, buffer, size=8192)
buffer.seek(0)
pd.read_csv(buffer, engine="c").to_excel(self.output_file)
```

However, I can't figure out how to replace the `buffer` in `copy_expert` with `psycopg3`'s new copy command. Has anyone figured out a way to do this?

Comment: That is what the docs are for. Read [psycopg3 COPY](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/copy.html). There are plenty of examples. FYI, there is no `copy_expert` in `psycopg3`.

Comment: Also see my answer here [Psycopg COPY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73623152/psycopg2-copy-from-is-inserting-data-with-double-quotes-when-whitespace-is-pre/73623435#73623435). It has both `psycopg2` and `psycopg3` examples.

Comment: I read the docs; there is no example with a buffer and a size. Thus, why I said: `However, I can't figure out how to replace the buffer in copy_expert with psycopg3's new copy command. Has anyone figured out a way to do this?` Thanks for the answer, an example like that in the docs would go a long way. I'll issue a PR.

Comment: Not following, from here [psycopg2 copy_expert](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert) `size` is only used for `COPY some _table FROM some_file` per docs: *size – size of the read buffer to be used in COPY FROM.*. In your case it would be a no-op. You should be able to use the `COPY ... TO STDOUT`  example from *Copying block-by-block*  to achieve the same as your `psycopg2` case. Just substitute a buffer for the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to writing a large query to a file through `psycopg3` in this fashion is to use a [`SpooledTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile), which will limit the amount of memory usage in Python (see `max_size`). Then after the CSV is written to disk, convert with `pandas`.

```py
from tempfile import SpooledTemporaryFile
from pandas import read_csv
from psycopg import connect

cursor = connect([connection]).cursor()
copy_sql = "COPY (SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE price > %s) TO STDOUT"
price = 100

with SpooledTemporaryFile(
    mode="wb",
    max_size=65546,
    buffering=8192,
) as tmpfile:
    with cursor.copy(copy_sql, (price,)) as copy:
        for data in copy:
            tmpfile.write(data)
    tmpfile.seek(0)

    read_csv(tmpfile, engine="c").to_excel("my_spreadsheet.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 1):

Data and table setup:

```
cat test.csv                                                                                                                                                            
1,john123@gmail.com,"John Stokes"
2,emily123@gmail.com,"Emily Ray"

create table test_csv (id integer, mail varchar, name varchar);

import psycopg

with open('test.csv') as f:
    with cur.copy("COPY test_csv FROM STDIN WITH CSV") as copy:
        while data := f.read(1000):
            copy.write(data)
con.commit()
```

Using a buffer:

```
buffer = BytesIO()
with cur.copy('copy test_csv to stdout') as copy:
    for data in copy:
        buffer.write(data)
buffer.seek(0)
pd.read_csv(buffer, engine="c").to_excel('test_csv.xlsx')
```

Since you are using Pandas there is also:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:@localhost:5432/test')
pd.read_sql('select * from test_csv', engine).to_excel('test_csv.xlsx')
```