# How to deal with empty values in psycopg copy to from CSV

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, psycopg3

I'm using psycopg3 to copy rows from a csv into a SQL table.

But in the CSV are some empty values that are represented with a ' '. So when it gets copied to a int value field, I get a `invalid input syntax for type integer: ""`

```py
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
                with cur.copy("COPY manycolumns...") FROM STDIN") as copy:
    
                        for line in csv.reader(data):
    
                            print(line)
    
                            copy.write_row(line)
```

I've tried to turn all empty values in the list to null. But is a very inefficient solution.  Is there an argument in how I read the csv that doesn't read empty values?

Comment: You have to translate the blank values within your for loop. Probably to a `none` which will become a SQL `null`.

Comment: Is it actually a quoted empty string `' '`?

Comment: If is is actually an unquoted empty string which the error seems to indicate see my answer here [COPY with FORCE NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73074229/copy-with-force-null-to-all-fields/73083429#73083429).